# Binning differences in dates as time-unit-aware numeric vector across years

Tags: r, date, posix

I need to calculate *"how many `x` units apart"* each element in a vector of POSIX dates is from a given reference date, where

- `x` is a "typical" time unit like *month*, *week*, *quarter* etc.
- the date vector can span multiple years
- the result needs to be a `numeric` vector

I have something, but it doesn't feel like a consistent approach that could be generalized (two different approaches for *month*  and *week*).

Possibly worth nothing: I'm generally looking for solutions that comply with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

### EDIT

"Consistent" in the sense that I would ideally, say, a solution that is always leverages `as.numeric(dates)` with some clever "time unit binning" afterwards. But for *months* I wouldn't see how this could be achieved as each month contains a different number of days (works for weeks as we can always safely say "a week contains 7 days").

In other words: for *months* I'd like to use something like `(as.numeric(.x) / (<something>))` just as I use `(as.numeric(.x) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7))` for *weeks*. It's that **`<something>`** that I'm looking for to have a generic way of binning differences in dates.

### Solution draft

Function defs:

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

normalize_time_distance_month <- function(dates) {
  dates %>%
    as.POSIXct() %>%
    purrr::map_dbl(function(.x)
      as.numeric(format(.x, "%y")) * 12 + as.numeric(format(.x, "%m")))
}

normalize_time_distance_week <- function(dates) {
  dates %>%
    as.POSIXct() %>%
    purrr::map_dbl(function(.x)
      (as.numeric(.x) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) %>%
        round())
}
```

Months:

```
# Months ------------------------------------------------------------------

dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-03-01"), length.out = 24, by = "month")
origin <- as.POSIXct("2018-05-01")

dates_norm <- normalize_time_distance_month(dates)
origin_norm <- normalize_time_distance_month(origin)

(time_diffs <- dates_norm - origin_norm)
#>  [1] -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#> [24] 21
```

Weeks:

```
# Weeks -------------------------------------------------------------------

dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-05-07"), length.out = 104, by = "week")
origin <- as.POSIXct("2018-05-21")

dates_norm <- normalize_time_distance_week(dates)
origin_norm <- normalize_time_distance_week(origin)

(time_diffs <- dates_norm - origin_norm)
#>   [1]  -2  -1   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14
#>  [18]  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
#>  [35]  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
#>  [52]  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65
#>  [69]  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82
#>  [86]  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
#> [103] 100 101
```

Created on 2018-05-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org/) (v0.2.0).

Comment: May be you can pass an expression as argument and then evaluate within the `map`

Comment: @akrun thanks for the suggestion. I edited the post in order to make it clearer what I mean by *consistent*. But of course your notion regarding generalizing the function itself via feeding it expressions is an important aspect as well

Comment: Do you really need `map` here as map is a loop while the example can be worked out with vectorization `dates %>% as.POSIXct() %>% {as.numeric(format(., "%y")) + 12 + as.numeric(format(., "%m"))}` should work as well

Comment: @akrun did try that, but didn't seem to work for me (but I also had limited time). But yeah, I think you probably could get around using `map` quite easily

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to pass expression as an argument and then parse it

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
normalize_time_distance <- function(dates, expr) {
 dates %>%
    as_tibble %>% 
    mutate(value = as.POSIXct(value)) %>%
    mutate(value = !! parse_expr(expr)) %>%
    pull(value)

 }

expr1 <- 'as.numeric(format(value, "%y")) * 12 + as.numeric(format(value, "%m"))'
normalize_time_distance(dates, expr1)
#[1] 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237
#[20] 238 239 240 241 242



expr2 <-  'round((as.numeric(value) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)))'
normalize_time_distance(dates, expr2)
#[1] 2513 2517 2522 2526 2530 2535 2539 2544 2548 2552 2557 2561 2565 2570 2574
#[16] 2578 2583 2587 2591 2596 2600 2604 2609 2613
```

Comment: Yeb, thanks. But as I tried to explain in the EDIT above, I'm more referring to a consistent/generalized way of dealing with different time unit in the same manner rather than a consistent handling of different expressions in `normalize_time_distance`. In other words: I'd like to conceptually align how `expr1` and `expr2` are defined

Comment: @Rappster  This seems to be generalized as it is only depending on the formula.  the `value` column is the default column created by `as_tibble`.  Otherwise, I am not sure how many arguments you want to pass.  If we check the formula in both cases, it is very different

Comment: @Rappster Another option would be have a key word 'month', 'week' etc and then do a `switch` statement, but that would not be generalized if you want to do any other calculation

Comment: For example, for month I'd like to use something like `(as.numeric(.x) / (<something>))` just as I use `(as.numeric(.x) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7))` for weeks. It's that **`<something>`** that I'm looking for, not how to feed different expressions to `normalize_time_distance`

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in intervals that are multiples of a day there is no point in using POSIXt class. It will only give rise of the possibility of time zone errors which you can entirely prevent by using Date class so from here on we will assume Date class.  as.Date can be used to convert a POSIXct object to a Date object.

There are two distinct cases in your question.  Intervals that are multiples of a day (day, week) and intervals that are multiples of a month (month, quarter, year).  These will have to be dealt with separately because there is not a fixed number of days in a month.

### Case 1 - interval is multiple of days

If the interval length is d days then if x and y are Date class objects the
number of intervals is

```
# x and y are Date class
(as.numeric(y) - as.numeric(x)) / d
```

where d is 1 for days and 7 for weeks.

### Case 2 -- interval is mulitple of months

If the interval length is m months then if x and y are Date class objects:

```
library(zoo)

date2ym <- function(x) {
   ym <- as.yearmon(x)
   b <- as.numeric(as.Date(ym))
   e <- as.numeric(as.Date(ym, frac = 1))
   12 * as.numeric(ym) + (as.numeric(x) - b) / (e - b + 1)
}

# x and y are Date class
(date2ym(y) - date2ym(x)) / m
```

where `m` is 1 for months, 3 for quarters and 12 for years.

### EDIT

Fix (2).

Comment: Nice, thanks! I'll think about the `Date` aspect. While months and weeks are currently the most common time units/intervals for my forecasting tasks, I do see potential intra-day use cases on the horizon, so there I would unfortunately need to rely on something like `POSIXt`